# Prove using vectors that, In any right triangle, the median from the right angle to the hypotenuse equals half the hypotenuse.

Tags: geometry, vectors, analytic-geometry

Prove this by using vectors, my friends tries using point A,B,C,D, and on the test, I did exactly what the professor

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: Let the right angle be at the origin, and then $\vec x$ and $\vec y$ are the vectors for the legs of the right triangle. The vector to the midpoint of the hypotenuse will be $\frac12(\vec x+\vec y)$, and the length of the hypotenuse is $\|\vec x - \vec y\|$. Can you compare their lengths?